# How to tell what files dominates my apk size?

Tags: android, apk

Is there a tool that reports what is the contribution of each file (resources, asserts, etc) to the total apk size?

Since the apk uses compression, relying on the original files size is inaccurate.  For example, the tool could create the apk each time with one file missing and report the size difference for each file.

My motivation is to identify candidate files for compression/simplification/removal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since APK files are really just zip files most programs which can open up zip files will open up apk's (Some you have to rename to .zip for them to work).

On windows you can try 7zip..

http://www.7-zip.org/

Once it is installed just right click on the APK file from within windows explorer.

Choose 7 zip, Open archive.

It will show what the size and packed sizes of each file are.

You can sort by packed size and see what is largest.